# Swagger-ui + Spring Security => localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html <= Not Found 404

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger

I've been doing some investment over this but i couldn't get anywhere, here is my current situation:

### **1. I'm using Spring Boot + Spring Security and here are my configurations:**

.
.
.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
public WebSecurityConfig(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
};

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                               "/configuration/ui",
                               "/swagger-resources/**",
                               "/configuration/security",
                               "/swagger-ui.html",
                               "/webjars/**");
}
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests(authorize -> {
        authorize
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll() //do not use in production!
                .antMatchers("/", "/webjars/**", "/login/**", "/resources/**", "/v2/api-docs",
                        "/configuration/ui",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/webjars/**").permitAll();
    } )
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .httpBasic()
    .and().csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**", "/api/**");
    http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
};
```

application.properties:

```
server.ssl.key-store: classpath:springboot.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password:password
server.ssl.key-store-type: pkcs12
server.ssl.key-alias: springboot
server.ssl.key-password: password
```

Swagger configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig { //} extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
@Bean
public Docket api(){
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("enide.logicon.backend.controllers"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .apiInfo(metaData());
}
```

.
.
.

---

- Own-generated SSL Certificate up&running, generated to fill the
  "editor.swagger.io" https requests needs & to make Basic Auth more secure.

---

.
.
.

- **WHY DOES NOT FOUND THE SWAGGER-UI.HTML PAGE? here you have my dependencies:**

.
.
.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

.
.
.

**

- Also Allowed all paths without need to log in with
  `antMatchers("/**").permitAll()` This allows "editor.swagger.io" to
  retrieve data from the API but not /swagger-ui.html, any ideas?

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well don't know why that -1 on my question, the answer was there.

What worked for me was changing the dependencies for this one:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
```